# Jenkins- How to pass parameter through the jenkinfile to trigger another job

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

```
build job: 'build_Test', parameters: [validatingString(name: 'version', value: '1.0.0.1'), string(name: 'TASK', value: 'build')]
```

I am trying to trigger another job via jenkinfile. The above script triggers the job but can see below error in the triggered job's console log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1350)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.matches(Pattern.java:1133)
    at hudson.plugins.validating_string_parameter.ValidatingStringParameterValue.createBuildWrapper(ValidatingStringParameterValue.java:87)
```

Comment: Is there field 'value' in `validatingString` ?  I don't see that field instead only 'defaultValue'

Answer (score 0):

ValidateString Parameters should have the following options. And it seems your regex is null.

```
validatingString(name: "test", defaultValue: "", regex: /^abc-[0-9]+$/, failedValidationMessage: "Validation failed!", description: "ABC")
```

Comment: still same error